# How can I add qt-mobility 1.2 to my sis file?

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-mobility, qt-quick

I have QT Quick app for Symbian that use qt mobility 1.2 for Map element representation. So I need to add qt mobility as a dependency to my sis file.
For qt mobility 1.1 it is very simple – just add one string to settings of smart installer. But I dont know GUID of qt mobility 1.2 that I can pass to that config. Do we have same sort of workaround??

Answer (score 0):

It's the same but QtMobility 1.2 isn't delivered by the SmartInstaller yet as far as I know.